# I need to get the stock details of S&P 500 for the given time and store them in csv format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, yahoo-finance

I want to get all the historical data for S&P 500 for a given time frame using yahoo finance in csv and was only able to get 64 stocks.

I have tried modifying the code but a `KeyError: 'Date'` keeps popping up.

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import pickle
import requests


def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        ticker = ticker[:-1]
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    return tickers


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):

    if reload_sp500:
       tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
       with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
          tickers = pickle.load(f)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
       os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)
    for ticker in tickers:
       #just in case your connection breaks, we'd like to save our progress!
       if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
          df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
          df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
       else:
          print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```

Run results and error displayed:

```
Already have MMM
Already have ABT
Already have ABBV
Already have ABMD
Already have ACN
Already have ATVI
Already have ADBE
Already have AMD
Already have AAP
Already have AES
Already have AMG
Already have AFL
Already have A
Already have APD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "finance6.py", line 43, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "finance6.py", line 37, in get_data_from_yahoo
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 387, in DataReader
    session=session,
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 251, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 165, in _read_one_data
    prices["Date"] = to_datetime(to_datetime(prices["Date"], unit="s").dt.date)
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2995, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Debodeep Kar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: When you download data from yahoo, sometimes it will create an error. If you make a pause in your download (for example, 30 seconds every 10 or 20 tickers), your chances of getting all of them improve, at the cost of time.

Comment: It seems that the tickers you get from wikipedia are not exactly the same as the ones Yahoo uses.

I found two types of issues:first, wiki uses 'BRK.B' while yahoo uses 'BRK-B' (you can fix that with python's replace). 
Second, web.datareader returns errors from tickers: CARR, CTVA, DOW, FOX, FOXA, HWM, IR, VIAC, OTIS